# ImagePickerController returning "image format with an unknown type" on device and simulator

Tags: swift

I've experienced following error code: `Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error`. I've seen several threads about this however none seem to fix the issue in my case. what am I doing wrong here is my code

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)


    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

This could be due to you not unwrapping the optional.

**Try changing this line:**

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

**To:**

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type UIImage`